# jquery find and click image in table row, on checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox, click, src

I have an ASP Gridview that has an img tag in one column and a checkbox in the next column. I would like to fire the click event (for the selected row) that I've put on the img when the user checks the checkbox if the src of the image includes a certain string.

Putting this `$("[src*=plus]").trigger("click");` in the click event of my checkbox works, but it fires the event for every row, not just the one the selected checkbox is in.
I've tried several things, the latest being `$(this).closest("tr").child("[src*=plus]").trigger("click");`, but I have been unable to get it to fire for just the one row.

How do find the correct img tag and fire it's click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function DoSomething(Obj) {
    alert($(Obj).attr('src'));
}

$(document).ready(function () {     

    $('.test').click(function () {        

    //if($(this).closest('tr').find('img').attr('src') != 'xxxx')
      //{
        $(this).closest('tr').find('img').trigger("click");
      //}
    });


});
<table>
<tr>
    <td><img  src="first_img" onclick="DoSomething(this);" style="border:double 2px red;width:100px;"/>img</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="test" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src="second_img" onclick="DoSomething(this);" style="border:double 2px red;width:100px;"/>img</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="test"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That does find the correct img tag, however it will always trigger the click event. How do I limit it based on the src value of the found tag?

Comment: $('.test').click(function () {        
       if($(this).closest('tr').find('img').attr('src') != 'xxxx')
        {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('img').trigger("click");
        }
    });

Comment: Thanks, that does allow me to find the correct img tag and only fire the event in case of certain values! Is there any way to work the wildcard (*) in, like I have in my question - so that I don't have to have the full location string?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better put more data attributes like `data-id` to each row, and use something like:

```
# suppose the row/element you want has data-id = 3

$("[data-id=3]").trigger("click");
```

Comment: I'm expanding upon the nested gridview functionality found here http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx and therefore can't add a unique ID to every image. Also, I only want to trigger the click event if the src is plus - I don't want it to fire once the src has been changed to minus.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use asp tags while creating the column? It can be done with template column using the data from the datasource you've passed from the code behind.

Comment: The field doesn't get related to any data from the datasource, it's just a hardcoded image put into every row `<asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="Images/plus.png" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>` and I only want the code to fire against rows where the src is `plus` (it gets changed by other code)